# Chef - PowerShell If states and functions

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I don't seem to be able to get any complex PowerShell to run in a chef recipe. The upload fails to Chef if I add anything like a IF or function param into the resource block. Is this just how it works and I need to code around it or is there some other way to make this work?

```
powershell_script 'Install' do
code <<-EOH
   If ((Test-Path D:\Chef) -eq $True)
{
Do something
}
    EOH 
end
```

Error returned is pretty blank, even wtih -n -V

```
FATAL: Cookbook file  has a ruby syntax error
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: The error is when it's uploaded into Chef. Knife cookbook reports an ruby syntax error with nothing more. no detail at all. I remove the If statements and it uploads ok....

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific error output.

Comment: The error is "FATAL: Cookbook file  has a ruby syntax error" there is no error output beyond that...

Comment: Are you sure that's the only thing you are changing? Otherwise that looks fine as Ruby syntax goes, the PS code is entirely contained in a heredoc string literal.

Comment: Yup. I've played around with this on and off for days it won't compile into Chef. I've tried other things now like "Param" - Same sort of issues, the PowerShell command isn't recognize by the Chef compile. This is very very strange!

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time looking at this, I've worked out the issue.

```
log 'Add features - Start'
  powershell_script 'install-iis-features' do
    code <<~CODE
    Function ChefLog
    {Param ([string]$logstring)
    $logfile = "D:\\ChefpsLogs\\Logfile.txt"
    $date = Get-date
    $date = $date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm")
    add-content $logfile -value "$date :: $logstring"
    }
    Cheflog "Testing"
    CODE
  end
log 'Add features - End'
```

The CODE <<~ 
CODE

Section being the fix, I've not used this before but after reading about it I guessed this was the fix.